# Split character strings in a column and insert as new rows

Tags: r, data.table

Although I saw similar questions and solutions, but I still couldn't solve my problem.
I want to split my elements in my data.table into single values and insert into new rows.

The data is like this:

```
dt <- data.table("0100"=c("9103,9048,9903,7837","8738,2942,2857,4053"),
             "0101"=c("9103,9048,9903","2537,1983"))
```

I want it to be like this:

```
dt2 <- data.table("0010" = c(9103,9048,9903,7837,8738,2942,2857,4053),
              "0101" = c(9103,9048,9903,2537,1983,NA,NA,NA))
```

Since I just start learning R, Please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 4):

```r
library(data.table)
```

Using `lapply()` we can process each column with a custom function. This function
first applies `strsplit()`, turning each column into a list with two elements. By applying
`unlist()` we turn the lists into vectors (of unequal length).

```r
dt_l <- lapply(dt, \(x) strsplit(x, ",") |> unlist())
dt_l
#> $`0100`
#> [1] "9103" "9048" "9903" "7837" "8738" "2942" "2857" "4053"
#> 
#> $`0101`
#> [1] "9103" "9048" "9903" "2537" "1983"
```

By setting the length of the second column to the maximum length of `dt_l`,
the second column is “filled in” with `NA`s.

```r
length(dt_l$`0101`) <- max(lengths(dt_l))
dt_l
#> $`0100`
#> [1] "9103" "9048" "9903" "7837" "8738" "2942" "2857" "4053"
#> 
#> $`0101`
#> [1] "9103" "9048" "9903" "2537" "1983" NA     NA     NA
```

Now we can turn it all into a `data.table` again.

```r
as.data.table(dt_l)
#>    0100 0101
#> 1: 9103 9103
#> 2: 9048 9048
#> 3: 9903 9903
#> 4: 7837 2537
#> 5: 8738 1983
#> 6: 2942 <NA>
#> 7: 2857 <NA>
#> 8: 4053 <NA>
```

Comment: Two liner: func <- function(L) lapply(L, `length<-`, max(lengths(L)))` and `dt[, func(lapply(.SD, function(z) unlist(strsplit(z, ","))))]`, the same functions and methods as yours, perhaps more compact. (I use that `func` mechanism a lot, I think it makes a lot of sense to keep around :-)

Comment: (I should look more closely before I close tabs ... that *should* have read: `func <- function(L) lapply(L, \`length<-\`, max(lengths(L)))` for the first line ...)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `splitstackshape::cSplit`:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(dt, 1:ncol(dt), direction = "long", makeEqual = T, type.convert = as.numeric)
```

**Output**

```
   0100 0101
1: 9103 9103
2: 9048 9048
3: 9903 9903
4: 7837 <NA>
5: 8738 2537
6: 2942 1983
7: 2857 <NA>
8: 4053 <NA>
```

---

A `tidyverse` solution could be :

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dt %>% 
  summarize(across(.fns = ~ list(unlist(str_split(., ","))))) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  mutate(value = lapply(value, `length<-`, max(lengths(value)))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,
              values_from = value) %>% 
  unnest(cols = everything())
```

Comment: Nice solution - need to check this library out.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `dyplr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt1 <- dt[,1] %>%
  separate_rows(`0100`, sep = ",", convert = TRUE) 

dt2 <- dt[,2] %>%
  separate_rows(`0101`, sep = ",", convert = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(`0101` = c(`0101`, rep(NA, nrow(dt1) - nrow(dt2))))

dt <- bind_cols(dt1, dt2)
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  `0100` `0101`
   <int>  <int>
1   9103   9103
2   9048   9048
3   9903   9903
4   7837   2537
5   8738   1983
6   2942     NA
7   2857     NA
8   4053     NA
```

Comment: I've removed a few inconsistencies in the code; please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is far from a clean solution, but it produces the result you want:

```
# our solution will rep the column with less elements, so we need to get the row
cutoff = dt[, sum(stringi::stri_count(`0101`, fixed = ","))+2]

# We split each string at the ",", unlist the result and convert to numeric
dt2 = dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ","))))]

# we replace the the rep'd values with NAs:
dt2[(cutoff + 1) : .N, `0101` := NA]
```

The big assumption here is that the `0101` vector will always be the shorter one.